# How to find an element by attribute value in XML via castor generated object

Tags: java, xml, mapping, castor

I am having trouble looking up elements by attribute value in the XML file via castor generated classes.

Castor does the mapping of XML to entity classes very good. However it doesn't provide means to find the element by name (assume that name is an attribute of the element). The API can only find an element by its index in the element list. At the moment it seems if I want to find an element by name I have to loop through the element list to find it. Because every class it unmarshalled has different fields it seems hard to write a generic method to find an element by name. Is there a better way to find an element from the element list by name?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I'm the [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead, and a member of the JAXB ([JSR-222](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) expert group.

---

Not sure about Castor, but you can do this easy enough with [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php).

**Customer**

Note how a condition `[@name='address']` is specified on the mapping via the `@XmlPath` annotation:

```
package blog.predicate;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name="node")
@XmlType(propOrder={"firstName", "lastName", "address", "phoneNumbers"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

    @XmlPath("node[@name='first-name']/text()")
    private String firstName;

    @XmlPath("node[@name='last-name']/text()")
    private String lastName;

    @XmlPath("node[@name='address']")
    private Address address;

    @XmlPath("node[@name='phone-number']")
    private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;

}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<node>
   <node name="first-name">Jane</node>
   <node name="last-name">Doe</node>
   <node name="address">
      <node name="street">123 A Street</node>
   </node>
   <node name="phone-number" type="work">555-1111</node>
   <node name="phone-number" type="cell">555-2222</node>
</node>
```

**For More Information**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html

Comment: Thanks the xmlpath in the annotation looks good but how to find a customer with a specific attribute value? In XPath it is easy to do but in Java code you need to iterate the entire customer list to get the customer.

Comment: @newguy - I'm not sure I understand.  I thought you were looking to map to an element based on an attribute value.  Are you looking for something different?

Comment: I am not looking for mapping because castor already does the mapping for me. I am trying to find a way to look for a node in the XML file based on the attribute value I provide, like something similar to the javascript method getElementByName(string name) or getElementByID(string id).

Comment: @newguy - You could use the javax.xml.xpath APIs in Java SE.